# Spark: get rows value from a Window

Tags: scala, apache-spark, window-functions

With spark I defined a Window:

```
val window = Window
  .partitionBy("myaggcol")
  .orderBy("datefield")
  .rowsBetween(-2, 0)
```

Then I can compute a new column from the window' rows, eg:

```
dataset
  .withColumn("newcol", last("diffcol").over(window) - first("diffcol").over(window))
```

This will compute, for each point, the difference in "diffcol" with the n-2 row.

Now my question: how can I get the "diffcol" of n-1 row, not the first nor the last but the intermediary one?

Comment: Can you add an example input data frame and expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, Window function `lag` would work better than `rowsBetween`, as shown in the following example:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
import spark.implicits._

val df = Seq(
  ("a", 1, 100), ("a", 2, 200), ("a", 3, 300), ("a", 4, 400),
  ("b", 1, 500), ("b", 2, 600), ("b", 3, 700)
).toDF("c1", "c2", "c3")

val win = Window.partitionBy("c1").orderBy("c2")

df.
  withColumn("c3Diff1", $"c3" - coalesce(lag("c3", 1).over(win), lit(0))).
  withColumn("c3Diff2", $"c3" - coalesce(lag("c3", 2).over(win), lit(0))).
  show
// +---+---+---+-------+-------+
// | c1| c2| c3|c3Diff1|c3Diff2|
// +---+---+---+-------+-------+
// |  b|  1|500|    500|    500|
// |  b|  2|600|    100|    600|
// |  b|  3|700|    100|    200|
// |  a|  1|100|    100|    100|
// |  a|  2|200|    100|    200|
// |  a|  3|300|    100|    200|
// |  a|  4|400|    100|    200|
// +---+---+---+-------+-------+
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it is exactly what I need! Do you know if there are any performance issue by not using .rowsBetween (will it keep all potentially needed data on nodes or will it just use what it needs...)?

Comment: @Rolintocour, unfortunately I don't know the inner working of Spark's windowing enough to give any authoritative comment on the performance difference using `first/rowsBetween` versus `lag`.